# Не могу сделать форму для регистрации и ввода пароля

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, веб-сайт

я учусь верстать сайты около двух месяцев, вот решил я сверстать макет сайта и сразу же в header'e появилась форма регистрации, полазил по сайтам и понятней не стало, если есть возможность, то можете помочь, пожалуйста???

Приложу код CSS и HTML а также фотку формы

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 10%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/*================  HEADER-TOP  ================*/

.header-top {
  background-color: #000;
  height: auto;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-size: 2.2em;
}

.letters-IT {
  color: #ff6600;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #C0C0C0;
  padding: 24px 18px;
  font-weight: semibold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}


/*================  HEADER-MAIN  ================*/

.header-main {
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  max-width: 450px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.logo-2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.95em;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 22%;
}

.description {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 390;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.line-shadow {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  width: 12%;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px -0.6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.lorem-ipsum {
  color: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.header-button {
  border: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
  margin: 40px 0 30% 0;
}

.btn {
  padding: 7px 30px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: white;
}

.header-button:hover {
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <title>Axit</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-top">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="logo">
          <h1>AX<span class="letters-IT">IT</span></h1>
        </div>

        <nav class="main-navigation">
          <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="nav-element">
              <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-element">
              <a class="nav-btn" href="#">About</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-element">
              <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-element">
              <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Reviews</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-element">
              <a class="nav-btn" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header-main">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="right">

          <div class="logo-2">
            <h1>AX<span class="letters-IT">IT</span></h1>
          </div>

          <div class="description">
            <p>MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES</p>
          </div>

          <div class=line-shadow></div>

          <div class="lorem-ipsum">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo.</p>
          </div>

          <a href="#" class="header-button">
            <div class="btn">
              <div class="button">Dowload</div>
            </div>
          </a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="signup">

    </div>

  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "не могу"? Форма может быть вставлена почти в любой элемент. Уточните свою проблему

Comment: Не могу понять, как её сделать,  чтобы была как на картинке и при этом работала

Comment: используйте тег form и css стили. Для логики обработки используйте стандартный http механизм (отправка формы) или js+ajax